# Multi Master Replication With One Slave

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

I'm in the middle of my little project here and i had some problem here, this is the detail of it.

I have 4 server, 3 server using for getting data from my sensor module and 1 is using for storing data. I try to using chained replication but it seems didn't work for me. I'm using multi master in 3 server and 1 slave in other server.

```
S1 <--> M2 <--> M3 <--> M4
```

Each server have different database, in `M2` I have database name `"PT100"`, `M3 = "PT100_2"` and `M4 = "PT100_3"`, so I created 3 database on each server.

The problem is `M2` cannot receive replication with database `"PT100_3"` from `M4`, even though `M3` is receiving `"PT100_3"` from `M4`.
`S1` even worst, it only can receive `"PT100"` from `M2`, even though there is `"PT100_2"` replication running on `M2`, nothing either on `"PT100_3"`.

What I want is, storing all the database from `M2`, `M3` and `M4` in `S1`, that's all.
How can I achieve this? Is it really possible to doing this and I just do some mistakes in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

3 Masters must be in a circle.  A Slave can hang off any of them.

However, Multi-master is a nightmare when any Master dies for any reason.  I strongly recommend against building such a system.

Replication systems *usually* expect *all* data to be on *all* servers.  There are many exceptions, but I await your justification for not doing that.